# R: pROC package: plot ROC curve across specific range?

Tags: r, roc, proc-r-package

I would like to plot a segment of an ROC curve over a specific range of x values, instead of plotting the entire curve.  I don't want to change the range of the x axis itself.  I just want to plot only part of the ROC curve, within a range of x values that I specify.

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)
rocobj <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$wfns)
plot(rocobj)
```

That code plots the whole ROC curve.  Let's say I just wanted to plot the curve from x=1 to x=.5.  How could I do that?  Thank you.

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve by plotting that? One way is to use `1-rocobj$specificities`, `rocobj$sensitivities`

Comment: I have data that form an empirical ROC that should only extend to the minimum specificity that exists in the data.  But pROC extends the ROC curve up the diagonal.  I have this: [link](http://jasonfinley.com/pROCplot1.pdf) But I want it to not plot the right part.  I think a variant of Dylan's solution will work.

Comment: The minimum specificity that exists in any dataset is 0. You can always have a threshold at -infinity and have all negatives classified as false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default plot function for roc objects plots the rocobj$sensitivities as a function of rocobj$specificities.

So

```r
plot(rocobj$specificities,rocobj$sensitivities,type="l",xlim=c(1.5,-0.5))
abline(1,-1)
```

achieves the same as

```r
plot(rocobj)
```

And

```r
plot(rocobj$specificities[2:6],rocobj$sensitivities[2:6],type="l",xlim=c(1.5,-0.5),ylim=c(0,1))
abline(1,-1)
```

Gets close to what I think you are after (plots from 0.514 to 1.0). I don't know enough about the package to know if the sensitivities can be calculated at a specific range, or resolution of specificities.

Comment: Thank you!  Some variant of this approach should end up working.  However, with xlim=c(1,0).  Directly plotting the specificities and sensitivities themselves was the breakthrough; I can choose just part of those lists to use, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The `plot` function of pROC uses the usual R semantics for plotting, so you can use the `xlim` argument as you would for any other plot:

```
plot(rocobj, xlim = c(1, .5))
```

Comment: Thank you.  However, this shifts the range of the x-axis, which is not what I want to do.  I still want the x-axis to display from 0 to 1.  But I want only a segment of the ROC curve to be plotted.